# How to unclip an image using rasterio?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, rasterio

I have a data transfer pipeline that is expecting an image in EPSG:4326 covering the whole world. The image I downloaded from my service provider is clipped to north America. Is there a way to reproject (the wording might not be correct) to the whole world and fill all the extra pixel with nodata? [image]

I'm usually working with Rasterio but I can adapt to other Python tools if necessary.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/476441/2856