# How to change the extent of an existing TIFF given shapefile bounding extent using rasterio's projection

Tags: python, rasterio

I'm currently trying to figure out how to re-create the following method using rasterio's reprojection method.  Currently in R there is a way to extend an existing GeoTIFF's extent using bounding boxes from say a shapefile and fill in the missing data with nodata values.

https://rdrr.io/cran/raster/man/extend.html

Now, I've tried doing a reprojection using Python's rasterio and I'm not able to get the number of columns and rows to match up (e.g. width and height shape) when changing the extent of the initial TIFF to match up to the shapefiles bounding box.

```
Shapefile bounding box:

min_x -- 10.0
min_y -- -90.0
max_x -- 70.0
max_y -- 9.0

def expand_extent(raster, left, right, top, bottom, res, file_name):
    dst_crs = 'EPSG:4326'
   
    with raster as src:            
        transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
        src.crs, src.crs, src.width, src.height, left, bottom, right, top, resolution=res)
        kwargs = src.meta.copy()
        kwargs.update({
            'crs': src.crs,
            'dst_crs': src.crs,
            'transform': transform,
            'resolution': res,
            'width': width,
            'height': height
        })
        
        with rasterio.open(file_name, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
            for i in range(1, src.count + 1):
                reproject(
                    source=src.read(i),
                    destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
                    src_transform=src.transform,
                    src_crs=src.crs,
                    dst_transform=dst.transform,
                    dst_crs=src.crs,
                    dst_nodata=np.nan,
                    init_dest_nodata=False,
                    resampling=Resampling.nearest)
                
    return rasterio.open(file_name)

shapefile_path = f'C:\\my_shapefile.shp'
gpd_df = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)

xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = gpd_df.total_bounds
xmin = round(float(xmin),3)
ymin = round(float(ymin),3)
xmax = round(float(xmax),3)
ymax = round(float(ymax),3)

raster_file = rasterio.open("C:\\my_raster_file.tif")
new_raster = expand_extent(raster_file, xmin, xmax, ymax, ymin, gt_res, tmp_raster_file)

print(rasterfile.shape) #Print's 3501,5501
print(new_raster.shape) #Print's 3500,5502
```

It seems like my reprojection's are off by 1-2 rows or columns everytime (last two print statements).  I'm simply trying to change the spatial extent of my existing TIFF to match the spatial extent of the shapefile.  Now the R link above has the method named "Extend" which has a property called snap, which can snap to a grid to align to the grid in some direction e.g. inside/outside.  I'm assuming this is why my columns/rows are off by just a little on every projection.  Does anyone know how to implement this "snap" functionality using Rasterio or some other Python library?

Comment: Did you look at the parameter resampling=Resampling.nearest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`rasterio.windows.from_bounds`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.windows.html#rasterio.windows.from_bounds) to create a window from your shapefile's extent that you can use to read the raster dataset. One of the parameters you can pass to the [`.read`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.io.html#rasterio.io.DatasetReader.read) method is `boundless`:

> `boundless (bool, optional (default False))` – If `True`, windows that
> extend beyond the dataset’s extent are permitted and partially or
> completely filled arrays will be returned as appropriate.

Note that rasterio windows have floating point (sub pixel)  precision so you need to round them to snap to the geotransform of the input raster.

```py
import math
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio import windows


input = "input.tif"
output = "output.tif"
extent = "extent.shp"


def snap(window):
    """ Handle rasterio's floating point precision (sub pixel) windows """
    # Adding the offset differences to the dimensions will handle case where width/heights can 1 pixel too small
    # after the offsets are shifted. 
    # This ensures pixel contains the bounds that were originally passed to windows.from_bounds()
    col_off, row_off = math.floor(window.col_off), math.floor(window.row_off)
    col_diff, row_diff = window.col_off - col_off, window.row_off - row_off
    width, height = math.ceil(window.width + col_diff), math.ceil(window.height + row_diff)

    return windows.Window(
        col_off=col_off, row_off=row_off, width=width, height=height
    )


def expand_extent(raster, extent, fill_value=None):
    window = snap(windows.from_bounds(*extent, raster.transform))
    data = raster.read(window=window, boundless=True, fill_value=fill_value)
    return data, windows.transform(window, raster.transform)


df = gpd.read_file(extent)
with (rio.open(input) as raster):
    profile = raster.profile.copy()
    data, transform = expand_extent(raster, df.total_bounds, raster.nodata)
    profile["transform"] = transform
    profile["height"], profile["width"] = data.shape[1:]
    with rio.open(output, "w", **profile) as expanded:
        expanded.write(data)
```

Comment: Yep, this works.  Thank you!